# How to get Token Vending Machine URL for DynamoDB AWS, iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have registered for `Amazon DynamoDB`. But I did not find how to get `TVM(Token Vending Machine) URL`.

While doing research for this, I got the link : http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566 which is for `JAVA`. where I need it for `iOS`.

Can anyone guide me for `TVM and iOS`? or any links for TVM iOS?

Comment: Are you asking how to authenticate with Amazon?

Comment: No, I am looking for How to get TVM URL.

Comment: There is no "TVM on iOS". These articles may help you understand the concept of TVM: [Authenticating Users of AWS Mobile Applications with a Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490), [Credential Management for Mobile Applications](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367)

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda : I am still little bit confuse. Actually what I am planning is just to keep my database on DynamoDB AWS. And then use it using DynamoDB API for iOS. While looking into demo provided by amazon it is ask for TVM. So still question is here...Do I need any kind of TVM ? (I am not using any other web-service, just communicate with iOS app to DynamoDB)